# Flowlayoutpanel scrolling many controls with mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a list that it's populated with usercontrols (~300 usercontrols // every UC has a PictureBox and 10 Labels). I display all of them in a Flowlayoutpanel but when I scroll down or up it is very slow and kinda unresponsive. I'm already using a DoubleBuffered Flowlayoutpanel and that 'trick' with SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout. What I'm trying to do: I scroll down with mouse -> when the first two usercontrols are not in the view anymore, remove them -> add two new usercontrols from the list at the bottom. And that should work also in the opposite way: scroll up with mouse -> when the last two are not in the view anymore, remove them -> add two new usercontrols from the list at the top.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0QnT.png)

I checked and tried everything that I found but it's not working...
Some links that I checked:

- [Fake-scrolling containers with very many controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808934/fake-scrolling-containers-with-very-many-controls)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc881e4d-6770-44f0-85ce-51456920f938/adding-4000-child-controls-to-flowlayoutpanel-freezez-the-scrolling?forum=winforms
- [Populating a FlowLayoutPanel with a large number of controls and painting thumbnails on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470863/populating-a-flowlayoutpanel-with-a-large-number-of-controls-and-painting-thumbn)
- [How can i implement the paging effect in a FlowLayoutPanel control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880236/how-can-i-implement-the-paging-effect-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control)
- [Winforms: Scrollable FlowLayoutPanel with thousands of user controls - How to prevent memory leaks and dispose objects the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379100/winforms-scrollable-flowlayoutpanel-with-thousands-of-user-controls-how-to-pr)
- https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/381141-flowlayoutpanel-paging-effect/

```
 private void FlowLayoutPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // move flowlayoutpanel with mouse
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
                return;

            Point pointDifference = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + mouseDownPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - mouseDownPoint.Y);
            if ((mouseDownPoint.X == Cursor.Position.X) && (mouseDownPoint.Y == Cursor.Position.Y))
                return;

            Point currAutoScroll = FlowLayoutPanel.AutoScrollPosition;
            FlowLayoutPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(currAutoScroll.X) - pointDifference.X, Math.Abs(currAutoScroll.Y) - pointDifference.Y);
            mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;

            
            //
            Point locationOnForm = UClist[0].FindForm().PointToClient(
            UClist[0].Parent.PointToScreen(new Point(UClist[0].Location.X,UClist[0].Location.Y+300)));
            if (locationOnForm.Y < 190)
            {
                FlowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();
                FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();
                FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(UClist.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray());
                FlowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();
            }   
        }
```

How should I do?

**EDIT**
This is what I was talking 'bout
[image: Pic]

Comment: IMO, among those links, the only one you should consider is TaW's answer: [Fake-scrolling containers with very many controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39810717/7444103). It's also (probably) the only one where this: `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear();` doesn't hurt your app's feelings (note that `.Controls.Clear()` doesn't *remove* the Controls, it just removes the references from the parent Container, so you cannot see them anymore, but those Controls - and their content - are still all there).

Comment: What *causes harm* are the Images you want to show: those 1000 images you'll load, one per UC, will be decompressed in memory. Each non compressed Image will take, say, 3 megabytes (a 1MB compressed image can be actually 3 to 10 times larger in memory - probably more than that), so you'll load 3GB of Images, plus all the rest. So you'll have to cache those Images and also load/dispose of the Images when the FLP is scrolled. Fortunately, TaW has already writen almost everything you need, you just need to add the caching part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Jimi! But from TaW's answer I don't understand this: float pageSize =  flowLayoutPanel2.ClientSize.Height / 
                  (uc1.Height + uc1.Margin.Top + uc1.Margin.Bottom);
vScrollBar1.Maximum = (int)( 1f * theUCs.Count / (pageSize)) + 9;

Comment: I don't know how to set (and where) the Maximum value of the VScrollBar. I tried putting the UClist.Count to the vScrollBar1.Maximum after I finished populating the list but that does not work...

Comment: You may want to move that code to a method that will set a new maximum value each time you modify the `List<UserControl>`: when you add to or remove from list one or more controls, call that method, pass the references of your `FlowLayoutPanel` container and the ScrollBar control and the size of the UC (assuming your UCs all have the same size, otherwise you'll probably have to show them *boxed* [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103)). The method can then perform that calculation and assign the `Maximum` value to the ScrollBar.

Comment: _I checked and tried everything that I found but it's not working_ Hm, you may have gotten things wrong. We can't know what you did..

Comment: I got it working with the vScrollBar like in TaW's answear :D!  But it's weird though because the last 10~20 usercontrols aren't shown properly (i'll upload a pic). I'll check that later. Now... how can I do the same thing inside the MouseMove function I posted above (because I need the flowlayoutpanel to be scrolling with mouse)?

Comment: Also make sure that the Image you're displaying inside your UserControl PictureBox is an appropriate size for the control (should be very small based on your description and details).  Loading a high res image and then letting the "Zoom" SizeMode take care of re-sizing is another common problem in these types of apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Idle_Mind! I already did that and didn't work... I just make the flowlayoutpanel bigger and that did the trick. Does it matter if the size of the Flowlayoutpanel it's not the same with the vScrollBar? How much should I put for SmallChange and LargeChange because sometimes I don't get all the usercontrols when scrolling and sometimes I get too much "blank page" (the flowlayoutpanel does not have usercontrols but I can scroll though).